# make long pages scroll in hybrid app (phonegap + jquery mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a JQM 1.4 + Phonegap 3.3 app in which there is a long text page. I would like it to be scrollable. But the touch scroll doesn't work in Android 2.3.

How to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: ok @Omar what is the best practice for iscroll + JQM 1.4 (should I favor this : https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview ) ?

Comment: this is widely used in jQM, try it.

Comment: @Omar, I just made my first attempt, it seems to work fine, but I would like to keep the option to use my app on a desktop and not to have this double scroll on the right that iscroll involves, so I have this isPhonegap function and I've try this :  `$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#welcome-page', function(){                
 //make it scrollable on android
 if ( isPhoneGap() ) {
  $("#contentFaq").attr("data-iscroll");
 }
});`  but it doesn't seem to make it....the page doesn't scroll. I guess my page event is not the right one, can you point me to the right path ?

Comment: I guess you can initialize the plugin anytime you want. Edit: try `.iscrollview("disable or enable")`.

Comment: @Omar with `$("#contentFaq").iscrollview("enable");` I get a `Error: cannot call methods on iscrollview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'`

Comment: Go through api and see if there's a function to manually initialize the plugin. It looks like it's auto-initialized.

Comment: Ok I had to initialize `$("#contentFaq").iscrollview();` and then enable `$("#contentFaq").iscrollview("enable");`

Comment: @Omar I am using iscrollview but it doesn't scroll to the bottom of the page, it stops a little before...do you have any idea why ?

Comment: could be a padding issue. try add extra padding at the bottom of ui-content or listview

Answer (score 0):

CSS overflow scroll doesn't work on android 2.x, so you have to do that by yourself. Some solution here:

1. use javascript plugin, like [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) or [touchScroll](http://static.uxebu.com/~david/touchscroll/)
2. make scroll button.